# unresolved dependency org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10 while building spark 1.2.0

Tags: dependencies, sbt, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

With sbt version `0.13.6`,

```
rof@railsonfire_1ad6bd90-94b5-0132-e2d9-5692d74b909b_7f496a9f21bf:~/bin/spark$ sbt/sbt --version
Using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ as default JAVA_HOME.
Note, this will be overridden by -java-home if it is set.
sbt launcher version 0.13.6
```

Spark 1.2.0 is failing with

```
rof@railsonfire_1ad6bd90-94b5-0132-e2d9-5692d74b909b_7f496a9f21bf:~/bin/spark$ ~/bin/sbt/bin/sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /home/rof/bin/spark/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/rof/.sbt/0.13/staging/ad8e8574a5bcb2d22d23/sbt-pom-reader/project
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-git:0.6.1 -> 0.6.2
[warn]  * com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-site:0.7.0 -> 0.7.1
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Loading project definition from /home/rof/bin/spark/project
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 -> 2.2
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Set current project to spark-parent (in build file:/home/rof/bin/spark/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/rof/bin/spark/}network-shuffle...
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1 -> 14.0.1
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: configuration not public in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: 'test'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.2.0 test
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:1.2.0 ((com.typesafe.sbt.pom.MavenHelper) MavenHelper.scala#L76)
[warn]        +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:1.2.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: configuration not public in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: 'test'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.2.0 test
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:243)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:158)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:64)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:119)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:156)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1282)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1279)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$84.apply(Defaults.scala:1309)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$84.apply(Defaults.scala:1307)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1312)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1306)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1324)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1264)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (network-shuffle/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: configuration not public in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.2.0: 'test'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.2.0 test
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 13, 2015 10:10:34 PM
```

What's actually the cause behind this, there was no problem with previous version 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `sbt/sbt assembly -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0` which also failed. My spark install is in /usr/bin so I tried rerunning with root permissions and that seem to fix it. I'm wondering if there's a failing write that is manifesting as a completely different error.

`sudo sbt/sbt assembly -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in sbt 0.13.10-RC1
https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2345

As the PR explains, this is due to the fact spark uses sbt-pomreader, and

> on Maven, Test configuration is considered private, and thus project dependency with test->test configuration may not under some condition: The condition is when someone resolves x:y:1.0 and you have a subproject named and versioned exactly that, and some other subproject tries to depend on it. (182374c)
>   This does happen when a project publishes to Maven and then someone grabs the code from Github, which is the case for twitter-util. I've run into this myself during sbt modularization, and apparently it happens with spark development too.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar messages when attempting to run *sbt/sbt eclipse*, removing the ivy cache (*~/.ivy2*) and repeating the operation worked for me. FWIW, on a subsequent iteration i realized i had omitted the hadoop options i had used in the original build, eg, running *sbt/sbt -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 eclipse* worked without having to remove the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
When I try to use a clear sbt env(no any jars in cache) the

`build/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 assembly`

worked, maybe you can try to use maven

[you can see here](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg24370.html)